# Skype calls not resolved

Tags: windows, skype

I'm facing the following problem with skype : despite being online, seeing my contacts online and being able to chat with them, I can't call them and they can't call me either. When someone tries, it rings forever. However, when I log out and log in again, all the missed calls suddenly appear. It still doesn't solve the problem, though.

Until recently, this problem was limited to a few contact. In order to solve it, I followed the steps described [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Can-t-call-a-specific-contact/td-p/212024):

```
1. Please stop any and all running Skype Client programs on your system.
2. Using your Windows Control Panel Add/Remove Programs uninstall Skype, when prompted to save your history, choose yes.
3. Using Windows File Explorer ("What you use to view files with") do:
%appdata%\skype
If you find a file called shared.xml right click on it and choose delete.
4. If you see a folder for the Skype name in question, click on it, if you see a file called Config.xml right click on it and choose delete.
5. Using the Windows file Explorer enter:
%programfiles%
Right click on the Skype folder and choose delete.
6. Reinstall skype
```

As a consequence, I can't call contacts I could before reinstalling.

A strange thing is that video calls work, even when I cut the video after the connection is established.

From what I saw from my researchs, it's a common problem. Is there a known solution ?

**Additionnal informations** : I'm using skype 6.14.0.104 on windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you contacted Skype's support staff for assistance and/or posted on the Skype forums.  This honestly sounds like an ISP level problem.

Comment: Well, skype forum is already full of this kind of problems, and no answers is working.

Comment: I saw similar issues fixed once by creating a new profile on the computer and installing Skype in there. This is totally anecdotal, and I don't know why, but it worked.